# Grassmannians Question, topology

Tags: general-topology

I am having trouble constructing an isomorphism from $Gr_n^{\mathbb{C}}(n + r)$ to $Gr_r^\mathbb{C}(n + r).$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Put a Hermitian(compatible) metric on $\mathbb C^{n+r}$. The Euclidean metric would be fine. Then send any complex $n$-plane to its orthogonal complement complex $r$-plane.